# apostrophes turning into &#39; when I get text from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, apostrophe

So I understand that apostrophes will screw up when you try to insert them into a database, but my apostrophes screw up before that even! Here is what my code looks like:

```
   String test = null;
   test= Textbox1.Text.ToString();
```

When I go through and debug this, and say I put in "How's it going" into the textbox1, I see that when i pass that value onto test, the apostrophe in How's turns into "&#39".

I'm guessing it has something to do with the encoding of the page? But I'm not really sure. Does anyone know? And is there a list of chars that will screw up like this so I can make a universal fix?

Comment: I don't see any difference from the 2 "How's it going", so what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. Apparently on stackoverflow, when I put that series of chars in and post it, it turns it into a apostrophe. I'm guessing it has to do something with the encoding?

Comment: Does `test = Server.HtmlDecode(Textbox1.Text);` not work for you?

Comment: What database can't handle an apostrophe?  Do you mean that if you design an application to fully support SQL injection attacks that it may develop issues?

Comment: I ended up using Simon's suggestion and everything seems dandy although the apostrophe is still being injected into the DB. I assumed that'd be problematic but apparently not?

Comment: It's not problematic depending on how you insert it. If you were concatenating strings it would be a problem.. but you're obviously not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ykbs7dz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It seems like you are getting an encoded string.

```
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Textbox1.Text.ToString(), myWriter);
String test = myWriter;
```

Comment: you can I just took this reference directly from MSDN as clear example

Comment: I can't select your answer Simon because your answer was only a comment on my original post, but your answer worked perfectly. test = Server.HtmlDecode(Textbox1.Text); is what I ended up using. Thanks! And as for the DB comment, it looks like my DB wasn't the issue although I assumed that the apostrophe would give it fits?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. I had solved it by changing content type of page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="application/xhtml+xm" %>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have two options

1. Replace your special characters like Single Quote with Say...Single_Quote and while retrieving from the database you can convert back to Single Quote while rendering
2. Insert the string as it is in the database. Now, while fetching from the database you can use Literal Control. This control provides three properties

   (a)  Transform

   (b)  Encode

   (c)  Transform

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Just store the apostrophes in the database.